# wrong route handling form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, routes

I have an expanded version of the devise edit registration form, and when I submit it instead of being handled by the update method, it is handled by the create method. And I can't figure out why.

When I submit the form in the log I get:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-08-05 20:49:28 -0600
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
```

in my view this is how I generate my form tag:

```
form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put,class:"form-horizontal" }) do |f| ... end
```

relevant output from rake routes:

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                 users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                        users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                   users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                        users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                        users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                        users/registrations#destroy
```

and the rendered form html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="edit_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden">
<input name="_method" value="put" type="hidden">
<input name="authenticity_token" value="snip" type="hidden">
...
<input name="commit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
</form>
```

I just went ahead and started commenting out large swaths of apparently unrelated code and it turned out that the following fields were causing the issue:

```
<input name="user[doctor_ids][]" value="" type="hidden">
<select multiple="multiple" name="user[doctor_ids][]" id="user_doctor_ids">
  <option value="2">House</option>
</select>
<input value="2" name="user[doctor_ids][]" id="user_doctor_ids_2" type="checkbox">
<input name="user[doctor_ids][2][token]" id="user_doctor_ids_2_token" type="text">
```

note the repeated `name="user[doctor_ids][]"`, still don't know why that was screwing with the routing but at least I can fix it. I was just trying to see what the params looked like when you submitted something like that in each case.

Comment: Try this once: `form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), method: :put, html: { class:"form-horizontal" })`

Comment: The `<input name="_method" value="put" type="hidden">` field is correct as is, and gets submitted correctly on post. But I tried it anyway and it makes no difference.